# How to avoid textbox space when it is hidden from the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am hiding some labels and text boxes according to radio button selection. It hides the label and dropdown lists but the space is there. How can I hide this space? My radio button click is:

```
protected void rbllist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbllist.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        lblcode.Visible = false;
        ddempcode.Visible = false;
        lblname.Visible = false;
        ddname.Visible = false;
        lbletype.Visible = false;
        ddtype.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lblcode.Visible = true;
        ddempcode.Visible = true;
        lblname.Visible = true;
        ddname.Visible = true;
        lbletype.Visible = true;
        ddtype.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is a Winforms project, right?

Comment: @Nahuel Ianni, No web application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies somewhere else. If you set the `Visible` property of a control to `false`, it's not even rendered on the page. This means that it can't even take up space on your page. Check for a table cell or div that might take up the space instead.

From the **[Control.Visible property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx)** page on MSDN:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a server control is rendered as UI on the page.

**Extra:**

Your code can be written much cleaner:

```
bool isVisible = !(rbllist.SelectedValue == "2");

lblcode.Visible = isVisible;
ddempcode.Visible = isVisible;
lblname.Visible = isVisible;
ddname.Visible = isVisible;
lbletype.Visible = isVisible;
ddtype.Visible = isVisible;
```

Comment: yes I had a required field validator now it works...Thank you :)